# CorePlot: Centering Ticks on right-aligned Y Axis

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot

I'm using CorePlot to draw a bar chart according to a specific design, and I'm having trouble getting the ticks on my Y-Axis centred. By that I mean that half the tick should be on the left side of the axis, and the other half on the right.

Here's the code I'm using so far:

```
CPTLineStyle *majorTickStyle = [[CPTMutableLineStyle alloc] init];
majorTickStyle.lineColor = GlobalColors.lightPinkColor.CPTColor;
CPTLineStyle *minorTickStyle = [[CPTMutableLineStyle alloc] init];
minorTickStyle.lineColor = GlobalColors.greyColor.CPTColor;

CPTXYAxis *y            = axisSet.yAxis;
//y.titleOffset         = 50.0f;
y.labelingPolicy        = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic;
y.majorGridLineStyle    = majorGridLineStyle;
y.minorGridLineStyle    = minorGridLineStyle;
y.axisConstraints       = [CPTConstraints constraintWithUpperOffset:0];
y.tickDirection         = CPTSignPositive;
y.majorTickLineStyle    = majorTickStyle;
y.majorTickLength       = 10;
y.minorTickLineStyle    = minorTickStyle;
y.labelTextStyle        = axisLabelStyle;
```

The image on the left is what the code above gave me, and the right is what the designer presented (i.e. what I'm trying to achieve):
[image: What I have so far] 
[image: What I would like to achieve]
(I'm not too worried abut the number of ticks, and the "L" on the end of the number is a separate issue entirely)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't supported right now. Please add an enhancement request on the Core Plot [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/issues/list).

In the mean time, you could use custom axis labels (`CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone`) and offset the label locations from the tick locations slightly.

If your app requires iOS 6 or later, Core Plot added support for attributed text in labels after release 1.2. This would make adding the small "L" easy. This would also require custom axis labels.

Comment: I did create an issue which has since been accepted: https://code.google.com/p/core-plot/issues/detail?id=538  What I ended up doing was creating a second Y axis with no labels and the ticks in the opposite direction.